# EventSourceException: No Free Buffers available from the operating system

Tags: c#, exception, roslyn, tpl-dataflow, microsoft.build

The full exception text is:

> EventSourceException: No Free Buffers available from the operating
>   system (e.g. event rate too fast).

I am calling this method approx a million times because of recursion. It does not stop, I just get the exception text in the Output Debug windown in VS2013. But it is super slow.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> RecursiveFindServices(ISymbol sym, Solution sln)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    var callers = SymbolFinder.FindCallersAsync(sym, sln).Result;  // this line may cause the EventSourceException  (try not to call Async)
    foreach(var caller in callers)
    {
        string name = GetMethodName(caller);
        if (caller.CallingSymbol.ContainingType.Name.EndsWith("Test"))
            continue;

        if (recursiveList.Contains(name))
            continue;

        recursiveList.Add(name);

        if (IsWebservice(caller))
            list.Add(name);
        else
            list.AddRange(RecursiveFindServices(caller.CallingSymbol, sln));
    }

    return list;
}
```

Does anyone know what this exception means and how to fix it. I am assuming that the slow speed is related to this exception.

`IsWebservice()` and `GetMethodName()` are pure string methods.

I am running Roslyn in a VS2013 project under .NET 4.5.2, can it be related to this?
I just installed this nuget package

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis

And then I had to copy over and include the following files in my project.

```
Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core.dll     (File Version 14.0)
Microsoft.Build.dll                     (File Version 14.0)
Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll              (File Version 14.0)
Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll           (File Version 14.0)
Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll          (File Version 14.0)
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll      (File Version 14.0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll     (File Version 4.5.24)
```

Any ide how to speed up the code or find the root cause of the exception will be helpfull. 
//Thanks :-)

Comment: You said you call it a million times. How often do you call it, 1M times per second, or a million times as fast as possible then done... etc

Comment: The exception is an *EventSourceException* - Your code is sending trace events to a source at too high a rate. Where does this exception occur? What is its call stack? Where do you log events?

Comment: BTW why are you blocking by calling `.Result` instead of using `async/await`? You are simply wasting CPU cycles this way.

Comment: @Mike159, I call it 1 million times as fast as I can. :-)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thanks! I have started using await. ... and I also tried to enable break on all CLR Exceptions in VS2013, but then it just crash the whole VS2013. :-(

Comment: Did await work? I was going to suggest slowing down your calls deliberately (temporarily) to check if it was a slow garbage collection cleanup or something more problematic.

Comment: @Mike159: No the await did not solve neither speed nor Exception. But inserting a Thread.Sleep(50) in the loop doubled the speed, because the Exception was significantly reduced. Now I guess I have to optimize the 50 ms sleep value by hand.

Comment: @thomasnn Interesting. It could well be something to do with garbage collection not releasing resources fast enough. Let me know what value works best in the end.

Comment: Since you don't provide the exception details, I'll simply guess this is raised by Roslyn itself. Which raises the question - *why are you doing 1M calls at all*? The resulting code will be hideously slow and essentially unusable. It's like trying to query a 1M row table one row at a time. Create a graph instead where each symbol will appear only once and not queried if it's already present

Comment: Or just cache the visited symbols (eg in a HashSet<>, Dictionary<>, whatever) so that you *don't* reprocess already visited symbols

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I just started using Roslyn and I am still eager to learn. Is there a way to create the entire reverse calling graph from any symbol? I end up with 1M calls, because it is a large project (20000 files) where we have a central enum with 2000 error codes. For each method in the service layer, I need to find out which error codes it can return.

Answer (score 2):

I run into this problem as well as I was developing a rendering method with VS 2013. I found a solution for stop spamming the console window with the message:

Go to the VS 2013 option menu:

*In German this is:*

**EXTRAS --> Optionen… --> Debugging --> Allgemein -->** (mark) **Verwalteten Kmpatibilitäsmodus verwenden**

*In English this is:*

**TOOLS --> Options… --> Debugging --> General -->** (mark) **Use Managed Compatibility Mode**

This will stop the message.

Comment: By the way, if you know how to reproduce this problem, could you add it to https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/2667405/eventsourceexception-exception-floods-debugging-session-and-slows-down-process?

Comment: VS 2017 gives you a prompt telling you that Edit and Continue is disabled if you have this enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Have faced this exception too!  Not sure if related or not my C: drive was full at that time, after freeing up some space, haven't got this exception.

Comment: Worked for me on my phone, where on SD card there was little of space, only 50-100 MB.