# EventSourceException exception floods debugging session and slows down process. How to fix?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I am experiencing this after upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and running my WPF application from Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 with the debugger attached.

While running some basic image processing operations the debug output starts getting flooded with `EventSourceException: No Free Buffers available from the operating system (e.g. event rate too fast)` messages, causing the process being debugged to slow down significantly.

Running the process without visual studio's debugger attached behaves normally.

I couldn't find much information online when I googled about it. It has something to do with EFW (Event tracing for windows), I don't know what it is.

The code base is not small so it'd be difficult track down the origin of the exception as asking Visual Studio to stop on all exceptions doesn't actually stop at this exception source.

Can anyone help on getting on getting rid of this exception?

**UPDATE**

I use Resharper Ultimate 2016.1. I did realize after uninstalling DotTrace some ETW service is uninstalled. But uninstalling Resharper didn't help, the problem is still there.

Comment: May not be a _real_ solution, but did you already try running Visual Studio with elevated privileges?

Comment: @khlr I did, it does not help at all.

Comment: Too bad :( But it was worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and posted an answer how to stop the message in VS 2013:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37389692/2936206

In summary, it is:

> Go to
>
> **TOOLS --> Options… --> Debugging --> General -->** (mark) **Use Managed Compatibility Mode**

Comment: This is not true. You can use Edit and Continue as you are used to. I use it since severeal years without any restrictions (VS 2013)!

Comment: It is true in VS 2017.  I haven't used VS 2013 in 5 years so I suppose it could be different.